# Cannot launch picoe/eto application on Mac OSX

Tags: c#, macos-high-sierra, eto

Currently I'm developing an application for both Windows and MacOS.
Created a template application for MacOS (10.13.4) using Eto.Platform.Mac64 (2.4.1) nuget package. The application is built for Release build. The problem occurs when trying to launch the .app bundle.

Currently tried:

- Opening the bundle using: open -a xxx.app. I got an error -54
- using: sudo open -a xxx.app. The error is -10810
- Giving all permissions for files inside for execution.
- Disabling GateKeeper
- Trying to launch the executable directly using mono, although the ETO platform checks if it's launched from .app bundle, and fails there
- Launching the .app from /usr/local/bin
- Launching the .app from ~/Applications/
- Building Eto.Forms for MacOS separately.

Everything seems to point to permissions issue, but I can't seem to understand what am I missing.
Since I'm new with MacOS in general (mostly familiar with linux), any suggestions/help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check Console.app > User Reports for a crash report?

You might get more info from the command line if you run it via /MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp

Also, what version of the mono framework do you have installed on your Mac?

Comment: Mono version installed is 5.12.0.226

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After checking the Console.app for logs I found out that com.apple.quarantine had marked the application as quarantined. 
After `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine MyApp.Mac.App/Contents/MacOS/MyApp.Mac` 
Everything works perfectly. 
Thank you Curtis for your suggestions.